# used disk space never released documents or/and shared container

Tags: ios, storage, disk

I am observing some strange behavior and am not sure what to make of it or how to get around it. The app may use a large amount of data and at some point GBs, I need to clear (delete) older data. I attempt to dynamically decide what and how much needs to be deleted.
The problem is that when I delete part or all of the data from the shared container, OS still reports that the app is using it. Restart did not help. Deleting the app solves the problem but given that I want to keep "newer" data and delete "older" data I do not want to delete the app. I also do not want the user to deal with this and want this to be done at the startup of the app.
Any suggestions?

Perhaps to make it more clear `FileManager.default.removeItem(at: folderUrl)` is used to remove folders/files. There is also trashItem method, but not sure it will change anything.

There are no errors, folders are deleted, yet OS reports space used by the app.

also may be similar to [FileManager.default.removeItem not clearing storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67720893/filemanager-default-removeitem-not-clearing-storage)

Comment: This is a question for SuperUser, not Stack Overflow. It's a general computing question; not programming-related.

Comment: why? this is specific ios related issue, I am programmatically removing folders in the shared container/app group container on the ios device, perhaps there is something else that I am not doing that needs to be done in order to actually release reserved space? possibly?

Comment: As written, it's not related to programming (no code, no errors...). As written, it seems like more of a general storage management issue. Your recent edit added mention of a method call - prior to that, there was nothing. I suggest editing your question to provide specific details (code, inputs, expected vs actual outputs, errors, and anthing else to help others help you).

Comment: Hopes this helps someone, but just by chance, I stumbled on the fact that if I just drop a large amount of data into the documents directory and then delete it using Files, that disk space will not get freed up. So perhaps as David pointed out it has nothing to do with the app itself or how it is written but rather what OS is doing. Perhaps just an iOS bug?